# What to check in AIX bootlist?

Tags: aix

It's OK that we can list the bootlist with:

```
2:root@server:/tmp/foo # bootlist -m normal -o
hdisk0 blv=hd5 pathid=0
hdisk4 blv=hd5 pathid=1
hdisk0 blv=hd5 pathid=1
hdisk4 blv=hd5 pathid=2
hdisk0 blv=hd5 pathid=2
2:root@server:/tmp/foo #
```

**Question:** But what needs to be checked on this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking for in particular, as there is a lot to be checked, not only for the bootlist output but resulting from that.

First, you need to check whether those two hdisks are available, that all the paths to them are available, that hd5 is synced to both of them including a current copy of the minimal ODM that is used for booting. Last but not least you should check whether both hdisks are actually bootable.

```
for disk in hdisk0 hdisk4;
do
lsdev -l $disk # check that both disks are available
lspv -l $disk # check that hd5 LV actually exists on both disks
lspath -l $disk # check that all paths to both disks are enabled
done
```

With `lsvg -l rootvg` you should check that the LV is of type **boot** and mirrored across the rootvg disks (column PVs) and also synced (column LV STATE)

If `ipl_varyon -i` does not show both devices as bootable, you need to [recreate the bootrecord and boot LV using bosboot command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/bosboot.htm). You should be aware of what this does, if not read the man page.

To check whether the minimal ODM on both boot devices is current, there is no non-trivial and non-invasive check that I'm aware of. Best [run savebase -v to both hdisk devices](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/savebase.htm) and check if the return code is zero.

**Some related information:**

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/my_lpar_always_boots_into_sms_why?lang=en
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/bootproc.htm
- [For more information on the bootlist command itself, see the

  man page.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/bootlist.htm)